# Why is my UIlabel displaying points of ellipsis (dot dot dot)?

Tags: swift

I am trying to print a text string that includes the current time on a UILabel.

```
var currentDateTime = Date()

let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.timeStyle = .medium

var savedNumberPlusDate = "\(counterValue) : \(dateFormatter.string(from: currentDateTime))"
saveLabel.text = savedNumberPlusDate
```

The first part works great, but the time comes in as points of ellipsis or dot dot dot (...)

[image]

Can't figure out what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Would love a comment from the drive by downvoters. Why? Couldn't find this anywhere. I thought it was a code problem. Seriously tripped up a rookie like me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because of label size - not all content fits into it's bounds, so rest is cut. There is UILabel property - `Line Break` that defines what to do with extended content. But the solution you are probably looking for is to adjust it's size. You can do it via autolayout constraints.

Answer (score 0):

When I have programmatically set UILabel.text, if the length of that string is greater than the length of the text I set in the storyboard, I've gotten the "..." truncation.

Instead of guessing the correct number of points to set as my label's width, I've set the text in the storyboard to be a template for the values I'll be setting programmatically. In your case, I would set the UILabel's text in the storyboard to be something like "9 : 99:99:99 XM".

Answer (score -2):

Well I found the answer. My UILabel on the Storyboard is too narrow, and so it is cutting off the time, and so adding the ...

The simple fix is to drag the label bigger.

The better fix is to use AutoLayout so this doesn't happen again. For example in this SO answer: `[How to created an expandable label in Swift][1]`.

Fixed it.
[image]